# Disable item from combobox even from events listener / ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Suppose I have this store :

```
var statsType = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['id', 'grayedOutComboItem', 'type', 'typeClass'],
data: [{
    'id': '',
    'grayedOutComboItem': 'x-combo-grayed-out-item',
    'type': '== Moyennes ==',
    'typeClass': 'mean'
}, {
    'id': '1',
    'grayedOutComboItem': '',
    'type': 'Moyennes journalières',
    'typeClass': 'mean',
}, [...]
```

and a combobox with this listener :

```
        [...]
        listeners:
        {
            'beforeselect': function(combo, record, index)
            {
                return ("" != record.data.id);
            }, [...]
```

It works because if click on an item that has an empty id, nothing happens in the combobox display. 
But the problem, is that it still triggers the event from the listeners. 
So when you click on it can still triggers stuff.

How to disable it so it does not trigger anything anymore !

:)

Answer (score 1):

To cancel the event so it does not trigger, use:

```
'beforeselect': function(combo, record, index, e) {
   if( "" == record.data.id ) {
      e.stopEvent();
   }
}
```

Comment: It still triggers event, for example if the combo is multiSelect: true, if you chose one active item then click on a disabled one, it erase the value of the first one.